# Rename Visual FoxPro table from C# application

Tags: c#, visual-foxpro

I have a c# application that works with VFP databases. I want to rename a table but I don't know how.

```
ALTER TABLE table RENAME TO newtablename;
```

this doesn't work for VFP databases and I don't know how to include VFP code in my c# application

```
RENAME TABLE table TO newtablename
```

Comment: RENAME TABLE only works for tables in a database container, not free tables. How are you connecting to VFP?

Comment: conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=VFPOLEDB.1;Data Source=" + txtCale.Text + ";"); --- in txtCale is the path to database

Comment: Is your data source a folder or a `.DBC` (or a [`.DBF` or `DSN` or..)](https://www.connectionstrings.com/vfp-ole-db-provider/)?

Comment: is a DBC, i connect to database using a path

Comment: Unfortunately `RENAME TABLE` is in [the list of VFP commands that are **not** supported by the OLE-DB provider.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt5d78fx(v=vs.80).aspx).

Comment: I wonder, what could be the reason that you want to rename a table. It is just a filename at the end and could be referred as something else logically.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use ExecScript to execute VFP code, but unfortunately not all commands work via VFPOLEDB provider.

If you are working with VFP tables, to do any structural change or create indexes etc use VFP itself. If you don't own VFP, then ask someone else to do that for you.